# How to disable the dropdown list for a specific element

Tags: html, css

I have a code like this

```
<div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFace" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <div class="border-bottom border-top f-sz-18">
        <a href="Cosmetic/Face" class="text-decoration-none text-dark">Face</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseFace">
    <div>
        <div><a class="text-decoration-none text-dark f-sz-15 ml-3" href="">123</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to disable so that the drop-down list does not work when following a link?

When I click on a link, for a split second I see how it starts to open, it's unpleasant

Comment: why not just remove the html if you don't want it to show?

Comment: When you click on the div, it should open the list, but when you click on the link, not

Comment: then you would need to add a click handler to the link and stop the propagation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation